# how do I prove this inequallity?

Tags: inequality

$m,n$ are integers bigger than 0.

I need to prove: 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+m}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+n}} \geq 1$$

I tried to multiply both sides by the common factor and raise both sides to the power of $m*n$ but it did not work for me, and I have no other idea how to proceed. 
 I don't want the full solution, but just a hint. 
Thank you.

Comment: Muck around with AM. GM???  Or raise the left hand side to a power and get something larger than itself or larger than $1$?

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

By [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) we have

- $(1+m)^\frac1n \le 1+\frac m n$
- $(1+n)^\frac1m \le 1+\frac n m $

Comment: where is that if and only if statement come from? why is it true?

Comment: Refer to [LINK](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Jensen%27s_Inequality)

Comment: thanks. but i never heard about this inequality, this is the first homework I got in calculus 1 course and this should be pretty basic, is there a simpler way to solve this?

Comment: maybe raise to the power of m*n will work? i tried do this and use the binomial formula, maybe there is something that i am missing..

Comment: Maybe try to the power $m+n$ (didn't do it)

Comment: @Omer I've revised my previous answer, indeed by Bernoulli the proof is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @gimusi isn't bernoulli inequality working only for natural power? and 1/n is not always  natural?

Comment: @Omer Please take a look to the given link, it is Bernoulli of course! But we can also call it with a different name, the importan thing is that it works! Bye

Comment: @Omer Notably take a look to the case $(1+x)^r $with$ 0\le r\le 1$ and $x\ge -1$. Do not hesitate to ask for any other clarification!